# Storing value in floating point variable

Tags: java, vb.net, floating-point

first I'll NOT asking why my multiplication is broken... because it's not, and I know how floating point store information, and why 0.69 * 10 = 6.8999999999999995

But I don't understand why I can store the value 6.9 in the my double variable if the IEEE 754 floating point system is not able to represent it correctly ?

Comment: Double type is fine when exact precision is not required.  For example,  when you calculate average daily temperature,  you don't normally care beyond a couple of decimal points.

Comment: The question is why I can see 6.9 in my variable...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*see*".

Comment: If I put 6.9 in a variable and I watch it in the debugger, I 'see' the value 6.9. But If write  "a = 0.69 * 10", I 'see' 6.8999999999999995

Comment: Yes, the **result** of `double` **calculations** is not precise. It is not a storage problem.

Comment: Nope, the number is also stored in binary format in memory and it logically should be erronous... but it's not. See: http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Floating point precision in literals vs calculations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28528386/floating-point-precision-in-literals-vs-calculations)

Comment: It's a kind of semi-answer... It tells why the result is not exact, and it tell that literals have some rounding to show us the real number...  but it's kind of not clear. 

Try this:
0.1 + 0.2 == 0.30000000000000004 //true
0.3 == 0.30000000000000004 //false

The value is not realy stored as 0.30000000000000004 and rounded for display

Comment: I suggest that you add a language-specific tag (like `java`) that you base your findings on. This may attract more people to your question.

Comment: The C# tag is erroneous here: C# does not display this behaviour. The byte representations for 6.9f and 0.69f * 10 are identical.

Comment: thanks, you are right

Comment: When stored in a double variable, the actual value stored for 6.9 is `6.9000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625`  I'm guessing that you only see 6.9 because the precision of Double is only 15 digits, so you don't see the digits that occur later in the value.

Answer (score 0):

Because `0.69` isn't 0.69, it's actually

0.689999999999999946709294817992486059665679931640625

which when multiplied by 10 is

6.89999999999999946709294817992486059665679931640625

which is exactly representable as a floating point number, and is printed as `6.8999999999999995`.

`6.9`, on the other hand is actually the next floating point number after this:

6.9000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625

(if you look closely, you'll see it's slightly closer to 6.9).